# Sending email through smtp-relay.gmail.com end up connecting to local smtp server

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, google-workspace

I have a Gsuite account. I setup a rule to allow SMTP relay through gmail servers, whitelisting my IP. Also, the FROM address is with my registered domain at Gsuite. And all my MX records point to google.

When trying to send a msg, the logs show that gmail accepts the connection, but in turn it passes is back to my local SMTP server.

Tried PHP PEAR mail & PHPMailer, same issue.

The logs start like this:

```
Connection: opening to smtp-relay.gmail.com:25, timeout=300, options=array ()
Connection: opened
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-mylocalhosting.com ESMTP Exim 4.89 #1 Wed, 17 May 2017 23:44:41 -0400 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
```

From there on, I can send emails if using authentication from my own system.

In short, I specify gmail relay server, but my messages end up going out from my local mail server. And I can't understand why.

UPDATE: If the PHP script runs as 'root', gmail takes the message and processes it as expected:

```
Connection: opening to smtp-relay.gmail.com:25, timeout=300, options=array ()
Connection: opened
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp-relay.gmail.com ESMTP 137sm1646549itk.4 - gsmtp
```

But I can't make it do the same as a regular user.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any DNS records pointing Gmail to your local hosting? Can you try an NSLookup on the server on the FQDN and see what that gets you?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: It's a setting in WHM SMTP Restrictions. [WHM Manual](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/SMTP+Restrictions)